# What causes this NameError? Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

My code is the IPRB problem from the web site rosalind.info. It works fine with the example data set values 2, 2, 2 for variables k, m, n. However when I change the variables for like 25, 25, 19. it gives this:

```
C:\Users\mNm\PycharmProjects\PySummer\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/mNm/PycharmProjects/PySummer/venv/Scripts/IPRB.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mNm/PycharmProjects/PySummer/venv/Scripts/IPRB.py", line 43, in <module>
    pr3 = float(pr31 + pr32 + pr33)
NameError: name 'pr31' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I couldn't find anything to try and I don't know what is causing the problem.

Thanks by now.

```
k = 2
m = 2
n = 2

whole = k + m + n
org = [k, m, n]

for i in org:
    if i == k:
        k_start = float(k/whole)
        for j in org:
            if j == k:
                pr11 = float(k_start * ((k - 1) / (whole - 1)))
            if j == m:
                pr12 = float(k_start * (m / (whole - 1)))
            if j == n:
                pr13 = float(k_start * (n / (whole - 1)))

    pr1 = float(pr11 + pr12 + pr13)

    if i == m:
        m_start = float(m/whole)
        for j in org:
            if j == k:
                pr21 = float(m_start * (k / (whole - 1)))
            if j == m:
                pr22 = float(m_start * ((m - 1) / (whole - 1)) * 0.75)
            if j == n:
                pr23 = float(m_start * (n / (whole - 1)) * 0.5)

    pr2 = float(pr21 + pr22 + pr23)

    if i == n:
        n_start = float(n / whole)
        for j in org:
            if j == k:
                pr31 = float(n_start * (k / (whole - 1)))
            if j == m:
                pr32 = float(n_start * (m / (whole - 1)) * 0.5)
            if j == n:
                pr33 = float(n_start * ((n - 1) / (whole - 1)) * 0)

    pr3 = float(pr31 + pr32 + pr33)

dom_pr = float(pr1 + pr2 + pr3)

print(dom_pr)
```

Comment: The message says what is wrong. You are trying to access `pr31` on line 43 before you have set `pr31` to have a value.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre]. It will help you and us understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you I will delete and resend the question in a more clear way. Sorry for my bad manner. This was my first.

Answer (score 1):

You only define `pr31` if `i==n` and some value in `org` is equal to `k`.